# HPC workload programming pattern

Tags: performance, hpc

I am new to HPC world. I want to know what are the considerations made while developing an application for HPC.In specific is it necessary to have a very good knowledge about the 
hardware/cluster before developing a HPC application? and what are the other considerations made?

Thanks in advance
Pradeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pradeep, a little more info on what you are trying to accomplish would help here.

If you are looking to solve a problem I would study your problem and see what limits you are hitting or expect to hit with a single thread implementation. Once you address those limits by building a bigger machine or using something like MPI or GPU/MIC cards you study your new implementation and see how well it scales. Running across 4 nodes(MPI) will not get you a 400% speedup but you can try and get as close as possible. Find your new bottle necks and try and address those. Is your code I/O bound? Do you need faster storage or the low latency and high bandwidth of something like Infiniband? Can you rewrite some of your code to make it faster or would a different library or compiler yield any improvements in performance?

If you are looking at getting into HPC from the systems side you should become familiar with the OS, probably Linux but it could be something else. Look at how it is built and how the components fit together: head node, storage, management network, interconnect. How are jobs submitted and executed? Submit some simple jobs and see how it works. It could be something like a "hostname; echo hello world; sleep 300" which will tell you where your job is running, produces some additional output, and remains active for long enough you can see it running in the queue. After that, you can find an MPI version of hello world you can compile and run across several nodes. Depending on how deep you wnat to get you can see how nodes are managed/installed. This could be a vendor supplied system or something homegrown that does RHEL/CentOS installs using DHCP, PXE, kickstart files, and custom scripts distributed with Apache. You could even try this on a small scale with a couple of old machines and something like the Rocks cluster distro.

There a lot of ways you can go with this but they all depend on where you want to end up in your HPC knowledge.

Comment: Thanks chuck for the reply. I am not going to write any application as such to HPC. But I am working on some tools for resource management in HPC. So, I wanted know what kind of considerations the application writers will make and how much knowledge they will have about the hardware.

Comment: End user knowledge will vary from novice to expert. Novice users will tell you their jobs are not running when they have problems and expect you to figure it why. Higher level users will be able to tell you why their code is not running or if it is not running well. If you want to get into resource management you will probably want to look at resource managers and schedulers. A short list would include Torque, Maui, SLURM, Condor, and forks of Sun/Oracle Grid Engine which are Open Source.

Comment: Thanks a lot chuck. The list of RM tools you have mentioned are really helpful. I have one more question, in case of HPC workloads is there any room for run time resource optimization? Or is it just initial provisioning?

Comment: Mostly, these tools will do initial provisioning based on what resources are requested and available. I believe that SLURM has support for changing allocated resources during runtime. The problem is some workloads like a week long MPI job will not be able to take advantage of additional nodes while other workloads may be more accommodating of change.